# jQuery class filtering and css transform delaying/blocking animation in section below it

Tags: jquery, css, hover, css-animations

My website is here:

https://thoughtpencil.com/testbed/

And I wanted a portfolio filter in the "our works" section.

I was trying to combine this pen:

https://codepen.io/creotip/pen/dfjeF and

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay_slide.asp

I have a snippet of my code here:

https://jsfiddle.net/nfhzj7e9/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var selectedClass = "";
        $(".fil-cat").click(function(){ 
        selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel"); 
     $("#portfolio").fadeTo(100, 0.1);
        $("#portfolio div").not("."+selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('scale-anm');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("."+selectedClass).fadeIn().addClass('scale-anm');
      $("#portfolio").fadeTo(300, 1);
    }, 300); 

    });
});
});
```

I expected that the hover would continue to work, but it only works before I actually fire the filter event.

As a workaround I have disabled the animations in the section below it, but I would be grateful for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing one more `.not(".overlay")` when you do `fadeOut()` on jquery.

You can add `$("#portfolio div").not("."+selectedClass).not(".overlay").fadeOut().removeClass('scale-anm');` to fix your problem.

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/sc16w47e/)